# How to load data from splitted gzip files into redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Can I load data from splitted gzip files into an amazon redshift table?

I can load data from single gzip file or from splitted text files.

But can I load data from splitted gzip files?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "splitted gzip file"? Do you mean you have multiple CSV files that have been gzipped (.gz) individually and they all contain part of the data you would like to load into a single Redshift table?

Comment: I have a huge csv file that has been zipped into multiple gzip files. When I zip it, we can define if we want to zip into multiple files.

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming here that you mean that you have multiple CSV files that are each gzipped.

First, upload each file to an S3 bucket under the same prefix and delimiter.

`s3://S3_BUCKET/S3_PREFIX/file0.gz`
`s3://S3_BUCKET/S3_PREFIX/file1.gz`

Then, execute the Redshift [copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) command:

`copy TABLE_NAME from 's3://S3_BUCKET/S3_PREFIX' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY;aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY' csv gzip`

- specify the S3 bucket and prefix
- include credentials that have permission to read the S3 objects
- ensure that the destination table already exists and has columns compatible with the CSV
- specify the csv and gzip options

[Also, it's a good idea to have your file count proportional to the number of nodes in your cluster.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_splitting-data-files.html)